# Передача данных Android Arduino по Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arduino, android-bluetooth

Мне необходимо только передать пару строк на ардуино, ничего от нее получать не надо. Но проблема в том, как только я пытаюсь записать данные мне прилетает вот такое.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)' on a null object reference
```

Собственно вот код, я впервые работаю с kotlin и android.

```
class Validation : AppCompatActivity() {
var mmOutputStream: OutputStream? = null
var mmSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_validation)


    resolve_Btn.setOnClickListener {bluetoothAdd() }


}

@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
private fun bluetoothAdd() {
    val mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth

        Log.e("Bluetooth ", "not found")
    }

    if (mBluetoothAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
        val pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (device in pairedDevices) {
                mmSocket= device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
                mmOutputStream = mmSocket!!.outputStream
                val message = "aaa"
                val msgBuffer = message.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset())
                mmOutputStream!!.write(msgBuffer)
                Log.e("Mac Addressess", "are:  " + mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.address))

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Найдено решение. Забыл открыть сокет.

```
 mmSocket= device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( 
                UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
                mmSocket.connect()
                mmOutputStream = mmSocket!!.outputStream
                val message = "aaa"
                val msgBuffer = message.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset())
                mmOutputStream!!.write(msgBuffer)
```